# zimbra: Sender IP must resolve (in reply to RCPT TO command)

Tags: linux, zimbra

I am running a Zimbra mail server version 7.2.7 on a Linux CentOS server.
My email address is xxx@azucarcolombia.com.

When I send email to yyy@prosalon.com.co, the email immediately bounces, and the bounce email says:

```
The mail system

<yyy@prosalon.com.co>: host mail.prosalon.com.co[174.37.44.242] said:
501 5.7.1 <xxx@azucarcolombia.com>... Sender IP must resolve (in reply
to RCPT TO command)
```

I have tried to change the zimbra smtp banner with the following command on the zimbra CLI, **but the problem persists**:

```
zmprov mcf zimbraMtaMyHostname correo.azucarcolombia.com
```

To be clear, this only happens when sending to some specific email addresses. Gmail, for example, works fine.

Comment: Ping to mail domain  and let me know the status

Comment: what do you mean? should I ping my mail domain (correo.azucarcolombia.com) from my terminal? If this is what you mean, the result of the operation is: 64 bytes from correo.azucarcolombia.com (181.48.150.131): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.013 ms

Comment: Have you use alias for mailid which is bounce?

Comment: When I ping the mail server that is bouncing my emails (mail.prosalon.com.co), this is the result: PING mail.prosalon.com.co (174.37.44.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from merakserver.com (174.37.44.242): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=119 ms

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the rDNS (PTR record) for the IP matches the SMTP banner. For example, if you `telnet x.x.x.x 25` and the banner returns mail.domain.com, you'll need to set the PTR to match the banner (i.e. mail.domain.com). You then need to allow sufficient time (based on TTL and DNS cache) for the changes to propagate before re-trying to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about Zimbra, but about configuring the DNS correctly. You should setup the reverse DNS (PTR record) correctly.